# Do I need Amazon ECS or EC2 instances when I am planning to deploy IBM Bluemix fabric images on docker?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

So scenario is to create a Blockchain network that is around a use case that takes input every 2 minutes. Now I need to do this on Bluemix hyperledger v0.6 and using docker. Should I deploy it on ECS or EC2 instances as blockchain is meant for multiple peers and they should be residing on each instance?

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix has an excellent documentation which provides step by step instruction on getting started with block chain here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ibm-blockchain-101-quick-start-guide-for-developers-bluemix-trs/index.html?ca=drs-

The above doc provides you information such as - setting up your network, writing the chaincode, writing client apps, monitoring your code etc. you can follow that article to get an insight on how to proceed further. Hope this helps.